# How is Unity's ExecuteEvents.Execute supposed to be used?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm just starting with Unity and got pretty excited when I saw that the Event System existed, and I could create custom events. The event I need is 'IInventoryMessage::NewItemInInventory', so I went ahead and created the interface for that, set it up on my Inventory.

Then it came time to trigger the event, and the documentation threw me a little.

`ExecuteEvents.Execute<IInventoryMessage>(target, null, (x,y)=>x.NewItemInInventory());`

My confusion is that it seems to be passing in the `target`.

My hope was the Unity would keep track of all the components with the message's interface and call that when it was executed. But it seems I have to pass in the GameObject myself.

Is it the case that I'm supposed to keep a list of all the GameObjects I want to receive the message, and the loop over them to pass them into `Execute`? Why do I need the EventSystem at that point, if I'm already looping over the objects I know need to be called?

Comment: I use normal c# events, they work as expected, ive not looked into the unity eventsystem and you havent made it sound like I should :D  with normal c# events you register to say "I want to know" to an event on an object and the object just initiates the event, so, those who wanna know get told

Comment: Had the exact same problem! Never found a proper resolve. Ended up with vanilla C# events and lots of unnecessary coupling.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ExecuteEvents` only inside my custom input system where the target it's always known and up to date (according to the pointer raycast). Whenever I want to send a message or trigger an action when something happened, I use the standard C# events, as BugFinder said.